# Is there a way to use the string literals of an object's, which is implementing an interface with index types, properties in another interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to build a form builder for React. For the first version the features include abstracting the form state, returning it when submitting the form and checking for required fields.

For the last feature I need to define an interface without known property names but the properties' objects do need to have a specific form. So I am using index types. But because I need to couple a field with a state property I would want the typechecker to see if that property name exists. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Right now it doesn't check if the property name exists, it just uses a string which in runtime has to correspond with the right property in the state.

I am using the latest version of TypeScript (at the time of writing anyway) which is 3.4.4.

This is what I have now:

```
interface Form {
  (defaultState: FormState, fields: any[], options: FormOptions): (newState: FormState) => JSX.Element
}

interface FormState {
  [key: string]: FormStateItem
}

interface FormStateItem {
  value: any
  required: boolean
}

interface FormOptions {
  title: string
  buttonText: string
  formClass?: string
  wrapperClass?: string
  showTitle?: boolean
}

interface Field<T> extends FieldFunction<T>, FieldOptions<T> {}

interface FieldFunction<T> {
  (value: T, callback: FieldCallback<T>): JSX.Element
}

interface FieldOptions<T> {
  id: string
  setId: (id: string) => Field<T>
}

interface FieldCallback<T> {
  (newValue: T): void
}

interface FieldWrapper {
  <T>(options: any): Field<T>
}

interface FieldBuilder {
  <T>(callback: FieldCallback<T>): Field<T>
}
```

I basically want the setId function to check the type of the FormState's property as a string literal, if that is possible. It would be great if this could be verified at compile time rather than runtime.

If I didn't ask this question right, or it could be better, let me know. I haven't posted a question here before. :P

### Edit:

I figured out how to let the typechecker check if the user of the library set's the right property of the state in setId, using mapped types. TypeScript is, however, unable to infer types when implementing an interface or type.

So, the new design is this:

```
interface Form {
  <State>(
    defaultState: FormState<State>,
    fields: Field<any, State>[],
    options: FormOptions
  ): (callback: FormCallback<State>) => JSX.Element
}

interface FormCallback<State> {
  (newState: FormState<State>): void
}

type FormState<State> = { [K in keyof State]: FormStateItem<any> }

type FormStateItem<T> = T

interface FormOptions {
  title: string
  buttonText: string
  formClass?: string
  wrapperClass?: string
  titleClass?: string
  showTitle?: boolean
}

interface Field<T, S> extends FieldFunction<T>, FieldOptions<T, S> {}

interface FieldFunction<T> {
  (
    value: T,
    callback: FieldChangeCallback<T>,
    validationCallback: FieldChangeCallback<T>,
    state: FieldItemState
  ): JSX.Element
}

interface FieldOptions<T, S> {
  id: keyof S
  setId: (id: keyof S) => Field<T, S>
  required: boolean
  validationCallback: FieldValidationCallback<T>
}

interface FieldChangeCallback<T> {
  (newValue: T): void
}

interface FieldWrapper {
  <T, S>(
    options: FieldWrapperOptions,
    parse: Parser<T>,
    validationCallback: FieldValidationCallback<T>
  ): Field<T, S>
}


interface FieldWrapperOptions {
  name: string
  required: boolean
  className?: string
  placeholder?: string
  wrapperClass?: string
  labelClassName?: string
  successText?: string
  invalidText?: string
  emptyText?: string
}

interface FieldBuilder {
  <T, S>(
    fieldFunction: FieldFunction<T>,
    validationCallback: FieldValidationCallback<T>,
    required: boolean
  ): Field<T, S>
}

interface FieldValidationCallback<T> {
  (state: FormStateItem<T>): boolean
}
```

This is an example of how it would be used:

```
type FormExampleState = {
  name: string
  age: '' | number
}

const defaultFormState: FormExampleState = {
  name: '',
  age: ''
}

const exampleForm = form<FormExampleState>(
  defaultFormState,
  [
    text<string, FormExampleState>(
      {
        name: 'Name',
        required: true
      },
      value => value,
      state => state.length > 0
    ).setId('name'),
    text<'' | number, FormExampleState>(
      { name: 'Age', required: true },
      value => parseInt(value),
      state => state.toString.length > 0
    ).setId('age')
  ],
  {
    title: 'Form Example 1',
    buttonText: 'Send'
  }
)

/* And inside a React component */
exampleForm(newState => console.log(newState))
```

So, I guess the question becomes: how can I design this in a way that enables TypeScript's type inference?

Comment: Could you also include example of how to use your lib

Comment: @hackape Thanks, I've updated the question.